# Cordova 3.4 and bootstrap-select issues on Android 4.1

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I'm using Bootstrap v3.1.1 and [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

When i set the value of the selectpicker programatically and use

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

it works in Android 4.4 or Chrome but not on Android 2.3 and 4.1.

Selectpicker shows always the same value and I can't change the option text programmatically too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with the newest version of Bootstrap (3.2)?

Comment: there are still issues. the current selected value of the selectpicker shows always "Nothing selected"